# How to make this webserver only accessible to your machine and server1.example.com?

Tags: linux, web-services, centos

I set up a default configuration webserver. And now I can't make this webserver accessible only to my machine and server1.example.com.

```
# chkconfig httpd on
# service httpd start
echo “This is a test.? > /var/www/html/index.html
# iptables -I INPUT -m state –state NEW -m tcp port 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Something wrong with in my script.

Comment: So, where is your script? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed tcp and -dport in your script:

```
# iptables -I INPUT -m state –state NEW -m tcp port 80 -j ACCEPT
```

You need to try this:

```
# iptables -I INPUT -m state –state NEW -m tcp -p tcp –dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```